# Do service apache2 restart and /etc/init.d/apache2 restart do the same thing?

Tags: apache-2.2, init.d

Do the two different syntaxes do the same thing?

```
$ service apache2 restart

$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: As a side note, the whole "service foo restart" thing annoys me because I don't have tab completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The backward compatible /etc/init.d/ scripts basically run service myservice start/stop/retstart instead of doing anything themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Service is nothing more than a shell script.

```
cat /sbin/service
```

At that top you will see it sets the SERVICEDIR to /etc/init.d.

The service script has a few other options such as

```
--status-all
--full-restart
```

That loop over all services. But the name you pass to it is matched to the init.d script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

To be precise:

```
service  runs  a  System  V  init script in as predictable environment as possible,
removing most environment variables and with current working directory set to /.
```

(from `service(8)`)

Answer (score 1):

In a way, yes. Actually upstart jobs will give a warning if started with `/etc/init.d/` while `service` command always works both for sys v init scripts as well as upstart jobs.